# Setting PGFPlots in Julia and Windows

Tags: windows, julia

I will be ever so grateful if anyone can provide step by step help to install PGFPlots in windows for usage in Julia.

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/sisl/PGFPlots.jl/blob/master/doc/PGFPlots.ipynb#PGFPlots

The website recommands:

> Pdf2svg. This is required by TikzPictures. On Ubuntu, you can get this by running sudo apt-get install pdf2svg and on RHEL/Fedora by running sudo dnf install pdf2svg. On Windows, you can download the binaries from http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/. Be sure to add pdf2svg to your path (and restart).

Nevertheless, not a computer expert I do no understand:

> To cross compile for Windows under Linux, simply install the relevant cross-compiler packages (for Fedora this is mingw32-cairo and mingw32-poppler and their dependencies) and then replace “./configure” in the compilation instructions above with “mingw32-configure”.

So if anyone can point me to the right direction that would be great?

Comment: I may be wrong since I don't tend to work on windows, but I believe what is implied here is that you need a functional LaTeX environment on your machine (also including pgfplots). I believe the most common LaTeX environment used on windows platforms is provided by the [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/) distribution, which conveniently provides facilities to install [packages](https://miktex.org/packages) via a built-in package manager, where [pgfplots](https://miktex.org/packages/pgfplots) is one of them. You should probably go down this route rather than attempting to cross-compile anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it:
1 Installing Chocolatey
open command line as administrator, and paste the following command

@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

2. close and re-open cmd as administrator to Install pdf2svg by running the command below:
   choco install pdf2svg
3. The installation is in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\pdf2svg 
   Pascal

Answer (score 1):

The second part you quote is about compiling Windows binaries for pdf2svg under Linux, which, I believe, is not what you are looking for.

Simply [download this Github repository they referenced](https://github.com/jalios/pdf2svg-windows), which already includes compiled binaries for Windows. Extract either `dist-32bits` or `dist-64bits` whichever is suitable for your Windows installation (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit) to somewhere in your computer . Then add the directory that contains `pdf2svg.exe` to your `PATH` system variable.

You will also need to install `pgfplots`, which is a LaTeX package. So you need a LaTeX distribution, as well. You can simply install [`MiKTeX`](https://miktex.org/) and then install `pgfplots` via its package manager/console.

That's it.